# How do I pass JavaScript values to Scriptlet in JSP and here is my code

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit").click(function(){

        int diff1=$(this).val();
        document.write("here"+diff1);
        if(diff1 > 31) {
            alert("You can't extend more than one month");
        } else {
            window.location.href = " thnks.jsp ";
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

another script is wriitten here which is a datpicker

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new Picker.Date('vista', {
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_vista'
    });
    new Picker.Date('start', {
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_jqui'
    });

    new Picker.Date('vista', {
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_vista'
    });
    new Picker.Date('end', {
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_jqui'
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my jsp code

```
<div  id="main" style="width:750px ; text-align:left;">
  <form class="contact_form" name="contact_form">
    <ul>

    <li>
      <h2>Extension of Date for Customer :- <%= alias%> </h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="jqui">Extend Date Here:</label>
      <input type="text" id="start" name="start" pattern="\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}"  value='<%= sdf.format(edate) %>' required />

      <!-- <input id=start name="edate" type="text" value='<//%= sdf.format(edate) %>'/> --> 
      <input name="env_id" type="hidden" value= '<%= rs.getInt(6) %>' />
    </li>
   <% 
    Date exp_date = start ;
        java.util.Date cur_date = new java.util.Date();
        long   diff= exp_date.getTime() - cur_date.getTime();
        long diff1=diff/(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        System.out.println(diff1);
       %>
     <li>
   <button id="submit" class="submit" value='<%= diff1 %>>' > Submit </button>
     </li> 
     <li>
       <p> <font color="red">Note: You can extend only upto one month </font></p>
     </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

Can you suggest me how can i calculate diff and pass its result in script where the condition should check.Is any other way to perform this action?

Comment: Javascript and java are very different, just so you know.

Comment: The JSP scriptlet run on the server when the page is requested, the JavaScript is run in the client browser - while you could jump through a lot of hoops, realistically the two pieces of code cannot easily share data

Comment: so suggest me another solution for this

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this then
create two hidden fields in you jsp and assign the values of them by your java script.
Then you submit the page or ajax call pass as querystring to jsp/servlet so you will have such values in jsp/servlet.

Comment: I am very new in this.Could u write a demo code for me

Comment: Thank u all but I used another date picker UI to perform this procedure.If you have to set a date upto 2 months limit then you can use datepicker.